# Using mixins with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I'm currently learning how to develop an app with Vuejs. I have a main.js file with the code for setting up Vue.js. I created a new directory /mixins with a new file api.js. I want to use that as mixin so that every component can use a function to access my api. But I don't know how to do it.

This is my `/mixins/api.js` file:

```
export default{
  callapi() {
    alert('code to call an api');
  },
};
```

This is my `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

import { configRouter } from './routeconfig';

import CallAPI from './mixins/api.js';

// Register to vue
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);


// Create Router
const router = new VueRouter({
  history: true,
  saveScrollPosition: true,
});

// Configure router
configRouter(router);


// Go!
const App = Vue.extend(
  require('./components/app.vue')
);

router.start(App, '#app');
```

How can I include my mixin the right way now, so that every component has access to the `callapi()` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can apply mixin globally using `Vue.mixin`

```
api.js
------

export default {
  methods: {
    callapi() {};
  }
}

main.js
-------

import CallAPI from './mixins/api.js';

Vue.mixin(CallAPI)
```

As the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) states you should use it carefully:

> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, including third party components.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use a mixin on a *specific* component, rather than all components, you can do it like this:

*mixin.js*

```
export default {
  methods: {
    myMethod() { .. }
  }
}
```

*component.vue*

```
import mixin from 'mixin';

export default {
  mixins: [ mixin ]
}
```

Another thing you might consider is using a component extension design pattern i.e. creating a base component and then inheriting from that in sub components. It's a little more involved but keeps code DRY if you have many components sharing many options and perhaps inheriting the template too.

I've written about it [on my blog](http://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/06/11/vue-js-extending-components/) if you're interested.