# Vue: Is it possible to put methods from the app.vue in new components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to split my project in more single-file-components. That works, but I still have many methods in my app.vue (the main project .vue). Is it possible to make extra components for each method? And if yes how can I link the variables to the new component?

For example I've got the following code in my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <headerbrand v-on:showece="vueshowece"></headerbrand>
    <sidebar v-on:showece="vueshowece" v-bind:selectedece="selectedece"></sidebar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import headerbrand from '@/components/headerbrand.vue'
  import sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      headerbrand,
      sidebar,
    },
    data () {
      return {
          showece:false,
          selectedece:false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      vueshowece() {
        if (this.showece==false) {
          this.showece=true;
          this.selectedece=true;
        }  
        else if (this.showece==true) this.showece=false;
      }
    },

  };

</script>
```

As you can see I've got one method "vueshowece" there which is called by an v-on:click event located in another component with more HTML code in it. I now want to put exactly this method in a separate component, but I don't know how to listen to e.g. the v-on:click event then since I can't reimplement it as  there because it would create a new copy of the whole HTML as I know.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Vuex`.  Create a store and use global state/actions in whatever components you want.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look into that! Thanks :)

Comment: I think you may be looking for [Mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Comment: use mixins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572237/1292050

Comment: if you just want call parent component method, there is a simple way. `this.$parent.someMethod()`. Be careful, Overall emit event from child is more recommended